# Can't find a button with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I've been trying to scrape this website [Link](https://ember-climate.org/data/carbon-price-viewer/) I'm interested in clicking the first **DONWLOAD** button. However whenever I try to find any element that is a button, I can't find any.

Here is the code :

```py
url = 'https://ember-climate.org/data/carbon-price-viewer/'
webdriver = create_driver()

with webdriver as driver:
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button')))
    except:
        pass
    ids = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button')
    for ii in ids:
        print (ii.tag_name, ii.get_attribute('class'))
```

Is there anything wrong with the XPath or is it an issue with the website itself?

Comment: Please try `//span[contains(text(),'DOWNLOAD')]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `xpath` is wrong, `Download button` is wrapped inside an `span tag` not `button tag`.

try this instead :

```
//span[contains(text(),'DOWNLOAD')]
```

also, I see it's in iframe, which can be located via

```
iframe[name='ETS']
```

`CSS_SELECTOR`, and we need to switch also to this `iframe`.

**so in sequence the explanation would be :**

1. You would have to `click` on `cookies button.`
2. `Download button` is in an `iframe`, we need to switch to `iframe` first and then we can interact with `download` button.
3. `download button` is a part of `span tag` not `button tag`.
4. Use `Explicit waits`.
5. Prefer `id, css over xpath`. (if they are **unique** in nature)
6. Launch browser in **full screen mode**.

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
driver.get("https://ember-climate.org/data/carbon-price-viewer/")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "cn-accept-cookie"))).click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[name='ETS']")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'DOWNLOAD')]"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```